# retrieve first map in list of maps groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a List of Maps like so:

```
[[id:abc, minScore:3.0], [id:cdf, minScore:1.0], [id:ihs, minScore:2.0]]
[[id:fgd, minScore:3.5], [id:hfg, minScore:5.0], [id:dkc, minScore:4.5]]
[[id:sfg, minScore:4.5], [id:owp, minScore:7.5], [id:axc, minScore:6.5]]
```

How do I get the first map i.e.

```
[[id:abc, minScore:3.0], [id:cdf, minScore:1.0], [id:ihs, minScore:2.0]]
```

or in fact how would I choose by index?

Comment: Does getting it by index not work? What other way would you want to use to get the nth element of a list?

Comment: `list[0]` or `list.get(0)`

Comment: or `list.first()`

Comment: Can we assume, that you missed the wrapping `[]` in your first code block and you actually have a list of list of maps?